# Camera Freeze when open app while call is running

Tags: ios, objective-c, avcapturesession, avaudiosession

I have created a **camera using AVCaptureSession**. I have configured that for **both Photo and Video recording modes**.

Camera and App is running fine. Also I **allowed background music play** ***(If user play song using Music App in iPhone)*** while open camera or recording video. It is also working fine. **(Attached image 2)**

I allowed background Music play with the help of this code

```
    AVAudioSession *session1 = [AVAudioSession sharedInstance];
    [session1 setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord withOptions:AVAudioSessionCategoryOptionMixWithOthers|AVAudioSessionCategoryOptionDefaultToSpeaker|AVAudioSessionCategoryOptionAllowBluetooth error:nil];
    [session1 setActive:YES error:nil];
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] beginReceivingRemoteControlEvents];
```

**Now if i receive a call**, minimize phone call screen by tapping on Home button and open app and want to open camera screen to capture image / record video, It opens but freeze with a image (Attached image(1)).

Now my requirement is, i want to capture image / record video while on phone call. I looked for another apps, and **Snapchat is doing same**, and i am able to record video while i am on call.

please help me, how can i achieve this. 
[image]  [image]

Comment: No, still searching for solution.

Comment: I have the same problem in my project. The same code is executed in both cases, but camera is somehow not opened. Do you have any ideas or solution so far?

Comment: @Surjeet, Did you got the solution I am facing the same, issue Please help!

Answer (score 4):

You need to use the `AVCaptureSessionWasInterruptedNotification` and `AVCaptureSessionInterruptionEndedNotification` callbacks and disconnect the audio capture while the session is interrupted:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(sessionWasInterrupted:) name:AVCaptureSessionWasInterruptedNotification object:self.session];
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(sessionInterruptionEnded:) name:AVCaptureSessionInterruptionEndedNotification object:self.session];
// note that self.session is an AVCaptureSession
```

-

```
- (void)sessionWasInterrupted:(NSNotification *)notification {
  NSLog(@"session was interrupted");

  AVCaptureDevice *device = [[self audioInput] device];
  if ([device hasMediaType:AVMediaTypeAudio]) {
    [[self session] removeInput:[self audioInput]];
    [self setAudioInput:nil];
  }
}

- (void)sessionInterruptionEnded:(NSNotification *)notification {
  NSLog(@"session interuption ended");
}
// note that [self audioInput] is a getter for an AVCaptureDeviceInput
```

This will allow the camera to continue running and allows it to capture stills / silent video

Now as for how to reconnect the audio after the call ends.. let me know if you figure it out, seemed impossible as of iOS 10: [Callback when phone call ends? (to resume AVCaptureSession)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38862181/callback-when-phone-call-ends-to-resume-avcapturesession)